# Diferença de Metódos com GetMapping e RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Bom dia pessoal. Qual a diferença entre os métodos abaixo e qual devo estar seguindo no desenvolvimento de aplicações Java Web

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Josemar, é melhor colocar o código no lugar da imagem do código

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas achei que era melhor deixar a imagem. Mas agradeço pela dica. Parece que fica mais visível mas tudo  bem e obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Resposta curta**

Não existe diferença na semântica

> Especificamente, @GetMapping uma notação composta que atua como um atalho para @RequestMapping (method = RequestMethod.GET).

**Leitura adicional:**

`RequestMapping` pode ser usado em nível de classe:

> Esta anotação pode ser usada tanto na classe quanto no nível do método. Na maioria dos casos, no nível do método, os aplicativos preferirão usar uma das variantes específicas do método HTTP @GetMapping, @PostMapping, @PutMapping, @DeleteMapping ou @PatchMapping.

enquanto `GetMapping` só se aplica ao método:

> Notação para mapeamento de solicitações HTTP GET em métodos manipuladores específicos.

**Documentação para leitura:**

[GetMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html)

[RequestMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)

Comment: Obrigado. Ficou bem claro a diferença.